# Combination of specific letters in many words

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database with a table called "sales person" which has a combination of names & surnames. On my report it must include the shortened name. Just the most left character of the Names and Surname combined. For example some has just one Name and a Surname, eg. "Pete Sampras". Combined it would show "PS" on my report. Some have more, like "Pete Steff Sampras". Combined it would be "PSS". For my own name is Johan vd Westhuizen. It must now look like "JVW". How would I go about it?

I am a beginner at this, and I'm not sure what to use. I have tried left(), but that's only for the first name

Answer (score 2):

You can split the word in the spaces, and then use the `Left()` function to get the first character for each word.

In addition, convert it to upper case and trim to remove *any* spaces (I don't expect any but just in case).

See an example:

```
Public Function GetInitialsFromName(ByVal fullname As String) As String

    'Array to hold the words
    Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(fullname, " ")
    
    Dim initials As String, idx As Integer
    
    'Loop each word, take the 1st letter and append it to the initials.
    'Trim and convert to upper case.
    For idx = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        initials = initials & StrConv(Left(Trim(arr(idx)), 1), vbUpperCase)
    Next
    
    GetInitialsFromName = initials
    
End Function
```

---

To call it:

```
Debug.Print GetInitialsFromName("Johan vd Westhuizen")
Debug.Print GetInitialsFromName("Pete Steff Sampras")
Debug.Print GetInitialsFromName("Pete Sampras")

'JVW
'PSS
'PS
```