# VBA Code to Generate a GAME ID with first characters of the words in GameName

Tags: vba

Private Sub GameButtonGen()

Public Function GetInitialsFromGameName(ByVal GameName As String) As String

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Split(GameName, " ")

```
Dim initials As String, idx As Integer

'Loop each word, take the 1st letter and append it to the initials.
'Trim and convert to upper case.
For idx = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    initials = initials & StrConv(Left(Trim(arr(idx)), 1), vbUpperCase)
Next

GetInitialsFromGameName = initials
```

End Function

Comment: Use the `Left()` function. `GameName = StrConv(Left(GameName, 5), vbProperCase)`. Just change number `5` to the number of chars you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function

Comment: If `GameName` consists of multiple words and you want just the first character of each word, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434680/combination-of-specific-letters-in-many-words/75434957#75434957